# reset all apple osx 10.6 fonts

Tags: macos, fonts, operating-systems, reset

over time I have installed a bunch of fonts that are either not properly licensed or I have not documentented as to where I got them from. Is there a way to reset all of the installed fonts back to the default install and remove all of the fonts I have installed?  I have done some research and have not come up with a solid way to tackle this.

Thank you for your help everyone :)